# Store pointer in array

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, strtok

I used `strtok` to tokenize an array. I wanted to store the char pointer, that strtok returns, into an array.

```
  char exp[] = {"1000 + 1000"};
  char operands[50];
  p = strtok(exp, " ");
```

Now I wanted to store the value of p (that is 1000) into the operands[i] array. I tried it like this:

```
memcpy(&operands[i], p, 49);
```

But it only copies a single integer.

Comment: Is this really C++ ? Why 49 as the last arg of memcpy ?

Comment: `strcpy(operands, p)`?

Comment: `std::string` is your friend.

Comment: "But it only copies a single integer." - that's what `strtok` does - put a NUL character in to `exp[]` after the first token, such that your `memcpy` (which has undefined behaviour because 49 is way larger than `sizeof exp`) copies "1000\0+ 1000\0" and about 40 other garbage characters.  Listen to Bathsjeba - if you use `std::string` you're less likely to screw up, and if you do you've a somewhat better chance to get the wrong string output instead of crashing your program.

Comment: I started programming in c, so thats why I still used a c function. (I see the 49, but won't make a difference in this case.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't actually want to copy the string pointed to by `p` into the array of characters `operands`. Instead it seems to me that you want `operands` to be an array of *pointers* to `char`, i.e.

```
char *operands[50];
```

Then you can just do

```
operands[i] = p;
```

(Note: `i` have to be a valid index, in the range 0 <= i < 50)

---

However, the above is a C solution to a C problem. If you're programming in C++ you should probably use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> operands;

...

operands.push_back(p);
```

Of course, if you're programming in C++ you should not use character arrays and `strtok` at all, but use the functionality in the [C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) for the tokenizing as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
char exp[] = {"1000 + 1000"};
char operand[50];
char* p = strtok(exp, " ");
memcpy(&operand[0], p, 5);
```

After running above code, in the char array operand,

the first 5 are assigned value

> operand[0] = '1' operand[1] = '0' operand[2] = '0' operand[3] = '0'
>   operand[4] =  0  // end character of char array

others are not assigned value '?'

> operand[i] = '?'